# How to interpret Nearest Neighbour Index (NNI) and Z-Score in Nearest Neighbour Analysis (QGIS)

Tags: r, point, qgis, nearest-neighbor

I performed a Nearest Neighbour Analysis in QGIS (3.4) via Vector > Analysis Tools > Nearest Neighbour Analysis on two different point patterns (13 archaeological sites in each). I am struggling to understand what the values mean. Do the NNI for both patterns indicate that the points exhibit clustering, since they are <1? Does the Z-score for point pattern #1 indicate clustering, and Z-score for point pattern #2 a random process? What is then the difference between NNI and Z-score to understand the behaviour of the point patterns? Is there perhaps a better way of calculating these values in R? Thank you in advance.

**Point pattern 1**

Nearest neighbour index: 0.7810443299917054

Z-Score: -1.5102844644713787

**Point pattern 2**

Nearest neighbour index: 0.9892311178623155

Z-Score: -0.07428022024573287

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the NNI, according to this page from [ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-average-nearest-neighbor-distance-spatial-st.htm):

*"If the index (average nearest neighbor ratio) is less than 1, the pattern exhibits clustering. If the index is greater than 1, the trend is toward dispersion."*

Regarding the z-score, according to this page from [Northern Kentucky University](http://ceadserv1.nku.edu/longa//geomed/ppa/doc/NNA/NNA.htm):

*"A negative Z score indicates clustering; a positive score indicates dispersion or evenness."*